# how to solve many overdetermined systems of linear equations using vectorized codes?

Tags: multidimensional-array, scipy, vectorization, linear-algebra, least-squares

I need to solve a system of linear equations Lx=b, where x is always a vector (3x1 array), L is an Nx3 array, and b is an Nx1 vector. N usually ranges from 4 to something like 10. I have no problems solving this using

> scipy.linalg.lstsq(L,b)

However, I need to do this many times (something like 200x200=40000 times) as x is actually something associated with each pixel in an image. So x is actually stored in an PxQx3 array where P and Q is something like 200-300, and the last number '3' refers to the vector x. Right now I just loop through each column and row and solve the equation one-by-one .How do I solve those 40000 different overdetermined systems of linear equations efficiently, probably using some vectorization techniques or other special methods?

thanks

Comment: Do you have different 'L' for different 'x'? If you do, then you probably don't have much room for performance improvement.

Comment: b is definitely different for different x. In general L is also different for different x, but it seems that the final results I get for using different L or same L is quite similar, so let's assume L is the same for all x first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can gain some speed by making use of the [stack of matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html#linear-algebra-on-several-matrices-at-once) feature of `numpy.linalg` routines. This doesn't yet work for `numpy.linalg.lstsq`, but [numpy.linalg.svd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) does, so you can implement lstsq yourself:

```
import numpy as np


def stacked_lstsq(L, b, rcond=1e-10):
    """
    Solve L x = b, via SVD least squares cutting of small singular values
    L is an array of shape (..., M, N) and b of shape (..., M).
    Returns x of shape (..., N)
    """
    u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(L, full_matrices=False)
    s_max = s.max(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    s_min = rcond*s_max
    inv_s = np.zeros_like(s)
    inv_s[s >= s_min] = 1/s[s>=s_min]
    x = np.einsum('...ji,...j->...i', v,
                  inv_s * np.einsum('...ji,...j->...i', u, b.conj()))
    return np.conj(x, x)


def slow_lstsq(L, b):
    return np.array([np.linalg.lstsq(L[k], b[k])[0]
                     for k in range(L.shape[0])])    


def test_it():
    b = np.random.rand(1234, 3)
    L = np.random.rand(1234, 3, 6)

    x = stacked_lstsq(L, b)
    x2 = slow_lstsq(L, b)

    # Check
    print(x.shape, x2.shape)
    diff = abs(x - x2).max()
    print("difference: ", diff)
    assert diff < 1e-13


test_it()
```

Some timing suggests the stacked version is around 6x faster here,
for that problem size. Whether it's worth the trouble depends on
the problem.